# Concat specific columns to new data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame `df` that looks like:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
3  A3  B3  C3  D3
```

I am trying to concatenate from `df` the index and columns `B` and `D` to a new data-frame called `finalDf` so my final output for `finalDf` would look like:

```
     B    D
0   B0   D0
1   B1   D1
2   B2   D2
3   B3   D3
```

Please see my code below:

```
finalDf= pd.DataFrame()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
     index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

finalDf= pd.concat([finalDf,df1['B','D']])
```

However running the code above I get a KeyError:

```
KeyError: ('B', 'D')
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: `df1[['B','D']]` ??

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to concat? It seems that you are trying to select to columns..

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like finalDf is empty so it is not necessary to concatenate

You can use

```
finalDf = pd.DataFrame()
finalDf["B"] = df["B"]
finalDf["D"] = df["D"]
```